# Сделать запрос через requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Не знаю, как правильно передать параметры через requests при отправке запроса на сайт? Когда я пытался множеством разных способов, я не получал необходимый результат, всё что имел это сообщение от сайта "Нет результатов".

Я хочу отправить параметры, которые есть на скриншоте на сайт `https://www.057.ua/map`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сами параметры:

```
jsonrpc: "2.0"
method: "catalogSearch"
params: {searchWord: "героев труда"}
```

Результатом должен быть текст на сайте:
`"вулиця Героїв Праці, Харків"`

Comment: `r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={"key": "value"})`, возможно, кириллические буквы нужно ещё закодировать через `urlencode` какое-нибудь, нужно проверять. Хотя может и нет, это же `post` запрос.

Comment: @crazyelf Я хотел получить совершенно другой ответ. Мне необходимо передать параметр params и чтобы на сайте я получил желаемый результат. Как отправить запрос с обычными параметрами я знаю, ещё раз повторюсь мне необходимо передать параметр params через requests, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.057.ua/map/jsonrpc'
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
    }
payload = {
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"catalogSearch",
    "params":{"searchWord":"героев труда"}
    }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

В `r.status_code` - статус, в `r.json()` - результат:

```
>>> r.status_code
200

>>> r.json()

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"75720d7d25f3b81ca6caefa987308e6c","result":"<div class=\"map-card map-card--lux\">            <div class=\"map-card__logo\">\n            <img class=\"img-fluid\" src=\"https:\/\/s.057.ua\/section\/cataloglogo\/subdir\/list\/upload\/images\/catalog\/000\/000\/744\/tkfiwulkauy_14762088511059521c995208e.png\" alt=\"\"\/>        <\/div>\n        <div class=\"map-card__info\">\n        <div class=\"map-card__title\">\n            <a href=\"https:\/\/operativnaya-poligrafiya.057.ua\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\u041e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u044f, \u043a\u043e\u043f\u0438-\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440 \u00ab\u041a\u0443\u0442\u0443\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439\u00bb<\/a>        <\/div>\n        <div class=\"map-card__info-items\">\n                            <div class=\"map-card__info-item map-card__info-item--address\">\n                    <svg width=\"12\" height=\"12\"><use xlink:href=\"#svg-map-placeholder\"><\/use><\/svg>\n                    <span>\n                        61000, \u0425\u0430\u0440\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0432, \u0413\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0435\u0432 \u0422\u0440\u0443\u0434\u0430, 24, \u0437\u0430 \u043a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u043e\u043c &quot;\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u0441&quot;                    <\/span>\n                    <div class=\"address-info\" data-address='{\"lat\":50.0233691,\"lng\":36.3366664,\"title\":\"\u041e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u044f, \u043a\u043e\u043f\u0438-\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440 \u00ab\u041a\u0443\u0442\u0443\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439\u00bb\",\"balloonContent\":\"61000, \u0425\u0430\u0440\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0432, \u0413\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0435\u0432 \u0422\u0440\u0443\u0434\u0430, 24, \u0437\u0430 \u043a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u043e\u043c \\u0022\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u0441\\u0022\",\"icon\":\"https:\\\/\\\/www.057.ua\\\/design\\\/images\\\/map_icons\\\/01.png\",\"address\":\"\\u0022\u041e\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u044f, \u043a\u043e\u043f\u0438-\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440 \u00ab\u041a\u0443\u0442\u0443\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439\u00bb\\u0022 - 61000, \u0425\u0430\u0440\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0432, \u0413\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0435\u0432 \u0422\u0440\u0443\u0434\u0430, 24, \u0437\u0430 \u043a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u043e\u043c \\u0022\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u0441\\u0022\"}'><\/div>                <\/div>\n                                        <div class=\"map-card__info-item\">\n                    <svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 578.106 578.106\" width=\"12\" height=\"12\"><path d=\"M577.83 456.128c1.225 9.385-1.635 17.545-8.568 24.48l-81.396 80.781c-3.672 4.08-8.465 7.551-14.381 10.404-5.916 2.857-11.729 4.693-17.439 5.508-.408 0-1.635.105-3.676.309-2.037.203-4.689.307-7.953.307-7.754 0-20.301-1.326-37.641-3.979s-38.555-9.182-63.645-19.584c-25.096-10.404-53.553-26.012-85.376-46.818-31.823-20.805-65.688-49.367-101.592-85.68-28.56-28.152-52.224-55.08-70.992-80.783-18.768-25.705-33.864-49.471-45.288-71.299-11.425-21.828-19.993-41.616-25.705-59.364S4.59 177.362 2.55 164.51-.306 141.56.102 134.216c.408-7.344.612-11.424.612-12.24.816-5.712 2.652-11.526 5.508-17.442s6.324-10.71 10.404-14.382L98.022 8.756c5.712-5.712 12.24-8.568 19.584-8.568 5.304 0 9.996 1.53 14.076 4.59s7.548 6.834 10.404 11.322l65.484 124.236c3.672 6.528 4.692 13.668 3.06 21.42-1.632 7.752-5.1 14.28-10.404 19.584l-29.988 29.988c-.816.816-1.53 2.142-2.142 3.978s-.918 3.366-.918 4.59c1.632 8.568 5.304 18.36 11.016 29.376 4.896 9.792 12.444 21.726 22.644 35.802s24.684 30.293 43.452 48.653c18.36 18.77 34.68 33.354 48.96 43.76 14.277 10.4 26.215 18.053 35.803 22.949 9.588 4.896 16.932 7.854 22.031 8.871l7.648 1.531c.816 0 2.145-.307 3.979-.918 1.836-.613 3.162-1.326 3.979-2.143l34.883-35.496c7.348-6.527 15.912-9.791 25.705-9.791 6.938 0 12.443 1.223 16.523 3.672h.611l118.115 69.768c8.571 5.308 13.67 12.038 15.303 20.198z\"><\/path><\/svg>\n                    <span>+380(93)565-00-65<\/span>                <\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n<\/div><div class=\"map-card map-card--premium\">            <div class=\"map-card__logo\">\n            <img class=\"img-fluid\" 

...

<\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n<\/div>"}
```

заберите оттуда html и парсьте с BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = r.json()['result']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: @jack-os Я рад, что нашёлся человек который смог ответить на мой вопрос, но bs4 не парсит полученный текст(

Comment: @MaximChyorny еще как парсит! )) вам же нужен не просто "вулиця Героїв Праці, Харків" со страницы, а, наверное, перечень организаций по улице Героев Труда?

Comment: @jack-os мне необходим только текст "вулиця Героїв Праці, Харків" со страницы

Comment: @jack-os извините, что немного запутал, если отправить просто "героев труда", тогда результатом будут организации, а если отправить "героев труда это какой район", тогда вы сможете получить желаемый результат, который я бы хотел получить от сайта, но bs4 не видит ничего связанного с этим

Comment: @MaximChyorny это потому, что самая первая карточка в ответе, где есть только название, прилетает не с `https://www.057.ua/map/jsonrpc` (тут 486 организаций с адресами, ссылками, временем работы и названиями), а где-то отсюда: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search`... поищите в devTools (может быть, что это ваша геолокация, определяемая гугл картами?)